# MouseWheelListener java- possible to detect out side Frame?

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt, mousewheel

Is it possible to detect mouse scroll wheel out side a JFrame I mean like on the entire screen?

I have looked up several sample codes but all of them seem to detect mouse scroll only inside their respective frames.

Some code would be really helpful

thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) `Is it possible to detect mouse scroll wheel out side`

is possible to determine that Mouse Cursor leave Container

2) `Some code would be really helpful`

a) tutorial inc. valuable examples

- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
- [How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)
- [How to Write a Mouse-Wheel Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html)

b) only [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/Catalog0260__Swing-Event.htm)